# Install -adobe-courier-bold-o-normal--12-120-75-75-m-70-iso8859-1 on CentOS 7, Linux

Tags: linux, centos, fonts

I am using software called SEISAN. It's earthquake analysis software. When I want to see the plot of waveforms I give the error "unable to get the font".
The software is installed on a CentOS 7 Linux system. When I remotely connect to it with a Mac it works well. The problem is when connecting with a Windows 10 machine, I give the error "unable to get font".
I know the proper font I need is "-adobe-courier-bold-o-normal--12-120-75-75-m-70-iso8859-1" but I could not find where to install this font. Does anyone know what package and where I must find this font?

Comment: How are you connecting from the Windows machine to the machine running SEISAN? (I’m asking because the font needs to be present on whatever system is handling the display, not necessarily the machine running SEISAN itself.)

Answer (score 0):

I am using x2go. At first I thought it is my windows problem of not reading the waveform fonts but I figured it out that it is related to Seisan availability fonts.